# how to work with deleted object on custom vector

Tags: c++

I know that std vectors can work with objects that are not default constructible. However, when I try to implement a slightly modified one myself, I cant seem to make such vector.

```
class A
{
    public:
       A() = delete;
       A(const int &x)
       :x(x)
       {}
    private:
       int x;
};
```

```
template <typename T, int N> //default constructor of the vector
CircularBuffer<T,N>::CircularBuffer()
{
    Size = 0;
    Capacity =N;
    Array = new T[Capacity];
    Start = 0;
    End = 0;
}
template <typename T, int N>
CircularBuffer<T,N>::CircularBuffer(const CircularBuffer& rhs) //copy constructor of the vector
{
    Size = rhs.Size;
    Capacity = rhs.Capacity;
    Array = new T[Capacity];
    Start = rhs.Start;
    End = rhs.End;
    for(int i=0;i<Capacity;i++)
    {
        this->Array[i] = rhs.Array[i];
    }
}
template <typename T, int N> //move constructor of the vector
CircularBuffer<T,N>::CircularBuffer(CircularBuffer&& rhs)
{
    rhs.Swap(*this);
}
template <typename T, int N>
void CircularBuffer<T,N>:: Swap(CircularBuffer &source) 
{
    swap(Size,source.Size);
    swap(Capacity,source.Capacity);
    swap(Start,source.Start);
    swap(End,source.End);
    swap(Array,source.Array);
}
```

When I try to make a vector with object A,

```
    CircularBuffer<A,3> v;
```

error: use of deleted function ‘A::A()’
I get this error which is obviously self explanatory. Anyone can help me solve this??

Comment: phrases like "is obviously self explanatory." imply that you would already know the issue and the fix. Instead assume that the reader knows nothing: Include the complete error message in the question together with a [mcve]

Comment: _"...I know that std vectors can work with objects that are not default..."_ not always true as it's per operation - live - https://godbolt.org/z/rnaozPz3P it all depends on the actions performed on the vector as stated here  - Template parameters - https://godbolt.org/z/rnaozPz3P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
Array = new T[Capacity];
```

which default constructs `T` objects.

`std::vector` uses *placement new* to construct objects when they are added to the vector.

```
Array = (T*)operator new(sizeof(T)*Capacity);
```

and (when you add the new item)

```
new(Array + i) T(...); // placement new
```

where `...` are the arguments you wish to pass to the constructor.

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the line `Array = new T[Capacity];`. This needs to default-initialize all members of the array, which it cannot do without a default-constructor.

`std::vector` gets around it by splitting allocation and construction with its [allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator). I recommend you simply use `std::allocator` as well. Otherwise you can use placement-new to construct the elements after allocating the required memory separately.